# Splitting H.264 with ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, h.264

I'm wondering if someone can help me with references or code snippet of H.264 files splitting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you have a video file encoded in H.264 that you would like to split into 2 or more video files? That would not be possible using Actionscript.

Comment: Why not? h264 is an open standard. Why not make it a bytearray and go thru it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It is not possible to split an h.264 file *directly* in AS3.

With out more information it is difficult to suggestion anything.  But I'll try.  What you can do is, somehow, communicate to an external process to split the file for you.  E.g.: Java, C#, Python, something running outside of the browser (or Adobe AIR.)

Splitting an h.264 video is non-trivial.  More than likely you will need to use third party software.  Two suggestions jump to mind:

- [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) (with x264)
- [MP4Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP4Box)

Again, this is non-trivial and there are more than one approaches to the problem.  Without more details, we cannot help.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to split h.264, it just might be difficult. Thibault Imbert made a
[FLVSlicer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=955)